# Git Merge Conflict with Yaml files

Tags: git, yaml

I'm using revision controlled yaml files to track packages associated with software versions and have multiple jobs (running on Jenkins) editing different parts of the tracking file. When I try to push the changes to the files I sometimes get a merge conflict depending on which part of the file was edited. For example:

HEAD:

```
...

Package6:
    Name: motorControl
    Version: 1.2
    Size: 341
Package7:
    Name: None
    Version: None
    Size: None
...
```

Local Copy:

```
...

Package6:
    Name: None
    Version: None
    Size: None
Package7:
    Name: eyeCandy
    Version: 3.2
    Size: 1087
...
```

Is there a different merge strategy that I could use to resolve this without needing to manually resolve conflicts?

Comment: Are these file automatically generated?

Comment: Yes they are and automatically updated as well.

Comment: closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211656/how-to-merge-yaml-file-with-conflicting-changes-on-two-branches/62213032#62213032

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the best may be to add this file to `.gitignore` and not version it. You could then generate it in a git-hooks when you update your files.

If that's not a solution, you can use `git checkout --theirs -- <path/file>` or `git checkout --ours -- <path/file>`. Then, you `git add` and `git commit`, there's still some step to do manually, but at least you don't need to resolve these conflicts manually in the file.

But the best is really to ignore automatically generated files.